# Android SpeechRecognizer should only be used from the application's main thread

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am trying to integrate some of Androids Speech APIS in my AndEngine based game.

I placed my code within the BaseGame activity - however this error appears at runtime:

05-06 23:51:28.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553): java.lang.RuntimeException: SpeechRecognizer should be used only from the application's main thread

How do I access the applications main thread? And how can I ensure my Speech code runs in it.

The setup is as follows:

Main Class - BaseGameActivity
SpeechClass

Main Class instantiates a new SpeechClass + calls its method - then I get the above error.

Please advise on how I can do this correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the `SpeechClass` on the main thread by doing something like this:

```
final SpeechClass c = getSpeechClass(); // get the speech class

View v = findViewById(R.id.anyview); //fetch a View: any one will do

v.post(new Runnable(){ public void run(){ c.doSomething(); }});
```

That should run it on the main thread. Might slow your UI down if `doSomething` takes a while, but you get to work that out.

Comment: Hi! I tried adding this but now it is throwing: 05-11 19:37:24.894: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2165): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Comment: Ah, that probably means some part of what you are doing is calling `requestFeature()`: you may need to do the setup of the speech bits before you set the Activity's content view, which would be a bit of an issue with the `post` method. Try creating a `Handler` and using that to run the speech class method.

Comment: I presume you mean one of these : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html but I dont have a working knowledge to workout what exctly would change!

Comment: A compact little tutorial (hooray Google): http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html