# speech recognizer delphi XE5

Tags: android, delphi

I find a trip "Android Text To Speech JNI Translation" in forum. But i want to convert Speech to Text, same as "Voice Recognize" .
And then i have a few code below:

```
{ TForm1.TRecognitionListener }

 constructor TForm1.TRecognitionListener.Create(AParent: TForm1);
  begin
    inherited Create;
    FParent := AParent;
  end;
 procedure TForm1.ButtonInitSpeechClick(Sender: TObject);
 var
  b : Boolean;

 begin
   b := TJSpeechRecognizer.JavaClass.isRecognitionAvailable(SharedActivityContext);
   if b then
   begin
     SpeechRecognizer :=       TJSpeechRecognizer.JavaClass.createSpeechRecognizer(SharedActivityContext);
     RecListener := TRecognitionListener.Create(self);
     RecognizerIntent :=     TJRecognizerIntent.JavaClass.getVoiceDetailsIntent(SharedActivityContext);
     RecognizerIntent.putExtra(TJRecognizerIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, StringToJString('en-US'));
     SpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(RecListener);

  end;
end;
```

It have bug :"SpeechRecognize should be used from application's main thead"
That's all;
Plz tell me what reason?, And, how to fix it.﻿

Comment: a simple google search reveals lots of answers on SO fot this (e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968646/android-speechrecognizer-should-only-be-used-from-the-applications-main-thread)

Comment: Are you have an example, i code in Delphi XE5.