# Cordova speech recognition without the standard google popup interface

Tags: android, cordova, speech-recognition

I’m trying to develop a cordova application with speech recognition, but I don’t want to use the standard Google popup interface. I’m basically using a speech recognition plugin: http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.manueldeveloper.speech-recognizer , but I want to set a RecognitionListener and use it for Recognition callbacks. That works perfectly in a native application developed using the code from this tutorial: http://www.truiton.com/2014/06/android-speech-recognition-without-dialog-custom-activity/ . So I tried to develop a similar solution in the plugin:

```
Activity a = cordova.getActivity();

SpeechRecognizer sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(a);
sr.setRecognitionListener(new listener());

// Create the intent and set parameters


Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, language);

if (maxMatches > 0)
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, maxMatches);
if (!prompt.equals(""))
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, prompt);

sr.startListening(intent);

cordova.startActivityForResult(this, intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

When I try to start the speech recognition I get an error: “SpeechRecognizer should be used only from the application's main thread". This shouldn’t be a big problem for someone who develops native android code, but I’m actually using phonegap to avoid native android code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

> Threading
>
> The plugin's JavaScript does not run in the main thread of the WebView
>   interface; instead, it runs on the WebCore thread, as does the execute
>   method. If you need to interact with the user interface, you should
>   use the following variation:

```
 @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if ("beep".equals(action)) {
            final long duration = args.getLong(0);
            cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ...
                    callbackContext.success(); // Thread-safe.
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins

Or this other question

[Android SpeechRecognizer should only be used from the application's main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968646/android-speechrecognizer-should-only-be-used-from-the-applications-main-thread)

Comment: which one of the two options? the code? or the link?

Comment: the code is copied from the PhoneGap documentation on the linked page.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom AngularJS directive to add Speech Recognition feature to your HTML button:

[ng-speech-recognition](https://github.com/Devniz/ng-speech-recognition)